# Spread figure/minipage/caption over the whole page vertically

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, minipage, fill

I have the following figure in a single-column article:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    % insert some space that fills the page vertically
    % and creates a gap between the first and second row of pictures
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A caption that describes all six images.}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

This creates two rows with 3 pictures each. All pictures have the same size. Since the figure almost fills the whole page vertically, I want to separate the two rows by a space to make it easier to distinguish where one row ends and the other starts. Because I am still working on the design of my document, I don't want to make the space a fixed size but adjust it so that the gap takes whatever vertical space is left on the page. I could, for example, just include an all white picture in between the two rows, but then I have to decide on a fixed height:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        % "B" could be an all white picture
        % but how heigh should it be?
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.325\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A caption that describes all six images.}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I know that this is not your real code, as it is not compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following solution satisfy your expectation:

[image]

For above image I use `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` where the rule height calculation consider `\textheight`, height of both rows with images, height of text in caption and estimated vertical distance to which contribute row separation in `tabularx`, `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` (altogether ~`3\baselineskip`).

Height of caption is measured by use of save box `\captbox` where the width of figure label is estimated on `11ex`. This require to save caption text in `\savebox`, hovewer this text can be used in caption only in case if caption style is `hang`. Otherwise, the caption text is necessary type in caption environment again.

If distance beween figures in one row is to big, it can be reduced by `\setlength\tabcolsep{<width}`. Default value is 6pt.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\captbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
\savebox{\captbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\hspace{11ex}
                    A caption that describes all six images. 
                    A caption that describes all six images. A caption that describes all six images. A caption that describes all six images.
                   \end{minipage} 
                   }
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-c}
                \\
\rule{0pt}{\textheight-180mm-\ht\captbox-3\baselineskip}
% 3\baselineskip is estimation of all not considered vertical spaces
    &   &       \\
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image-c}
                \\
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{A caption that describes all six images.
    A caption that describes all six images. A caption that describes all six images. A caption that describes all six images.
        }
\label{fig:mycomplicatedimageset}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```